# Data Structures Theory and Quantifier Expressions Confusing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I have questions on an assignment that want me to show things such as:

$∃m∈Z+,∀n∈m..+∞, 5−100/n > 0$

I am having a hard time grasping the concepts around how to "show" this.

Trying to convert it to plain English I have something like this:

"There exists a positive integer $m$ for every positive $n$ to infinity that satisfies $5-100/n > 0$"

If I am interpreting the question correctly that is step one, however from there I am really confused conceptually what to do and what is required. How can I show this?

Comment: The question seems to be incomplete. There is no $m$ in your final expression.

Comment: @AnuragA that is the exact question I was given, and many more that follow are exactly like this. $m$ is used in the forall stating that n satisfies a specific $n$ to infinity.

Comment: I think what you wrote as $n \in m..+\infty$ is incorrect. It should be $n \in [m, \infty)$. In which case the question reads: there exists an integer $m$ such that for every $n$ in the interval $[m,\infty)$ we have $5-100/n>0$.

Comment: @AnuragA I did not write it, that is straight from my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $n=1$ : $100/n=100/1=100$ and $5-100 < 0$.

With $n=20$, we have $100/20=5$ and thus : $5 - 5 = 0$.

But for $n > 20$ we have that $100/n < 5$, and thus $5 -100/n > 0$.

Thus, it is true that :

> exists $m \in \mathbb Z_+$ such that : for all $n > m$ :
>
> > $5 - \frac {100} n > 0$.

Comment: So essentially to prove these kind of questions it is a matter of finding a number that proves the equation? That is what it looks like you did. So in this case any $n > 20$ satisfies the equation, and therefore there exists a positive integer $m$ which satisfies the equation? I am just confused though why the $m$ is even used. Couldn't it just be an $n ∈ Z+$ and not even use an $m$ and still be the same question?

Comment: @Fogest - if we leave $m$ the statement will be : $\forall n \in \mathbb Z_+ : 5 - 100/n > 0$, which is plainly *false* (consider $n=1$ in my answer).

Comment: What if it instead was $∃n$?

Comment: @Fogest - if instead we have $\exists n \ldots$ it is again *true* : with e.g. $n=100 : 5 - 100/100 > 0$.